# iPhone app on iPad iOS8 strange adaptation

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller

i have created an app just for iPhone (iOS 8) but when i run it on iPad (iOS 8) the view controllers are adapted to the screen size of the iPad. I don't remember this beahaviour. Just few days ago when i test the iphone app on ipad its size was the same but just bigger with bad resolution and a "2X" button in the bottom-right corner. How can i disable this new behavior and return to the old one?

ps: sorry for bad english. Here is a screen for understanding what i mean:

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Did you set the device type to 'universal' in 'deployment info'?

Comment: I have the same problem. When I added the LaunchImage.xib file for supporting iPhone 6 and 6 Plus screens, this problem started.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use storyboard for handling splashscreen?
If so, it's a known issue of iOS 8 (fixed in iOS 8.1).

You can prevent this from happening by using the `UILaunchStoryboardName~iphone` key (instead of `UILaunchStoryboardName`) in your `Info.plist` file.